# Extracting the elements from a loop of sets/ lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of integers with the zero removed

```
Delete[Range[512/2, -512/2, -1], 257]
```

and I want to get the elements before and after a number within the list.

For example, if I want to get 5 elements before and after the number -255 in the list I should get:

> {-250, -251, -252, -253, -254, -255, -256, 256, 255, 254, 253}

This makes the list look like, if we visualize it, a loop of numbers that goes on like:

> .... 256 ... -256 , 256 ... -256 , 256...-256 ....

How can I do this?.

Comment: It might be `Partition`?

Comment: I am not sure what `Partition` will look like but the result should be a list of numbers like `{-250, -251, -252, -253, -254, -255, -256, 256, 255, 254, 253}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[lst_, elem_, n_] := Module[{pos = Position[lst, elem][[1, 1]]}, 
  lst[[Mod[Range[pos - n, pos + n], Length @ lst, 1]]]]
```

**Examples:**

```
f[lst, -255, 5]
```

> {-250, -251, -252, -253, -254, -255, -256, 256, 255, 254, 253}

```
f[lst, 251, 7]
```

> {-255, -256, 256, 255, 254, 253, 252, 251, 250, 249, 248, 247, 246,
>   245, 244}